# facebook integration in windows 8

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have successfully integrated facebook in my windows8 app. Referred to [this link](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/tutorial/) for integration, its a great article. Now the problem is when I click on login button in my app a dialog opens up (as you can see in screenshot) showing username and password box plus Login and Cancel button, I want that when user click on cancel button(circled with red in pic) user is navigated back to my page. Currently I am not getting any click call back for this click [image]

Comment: Is the flow not entering to the exception? `catch (InvalidOperationException e)`

Comment: Did you try listening to the "Navigating" event of the browser control to detect a cancel?

Comment: @Shadowfax InvalidOperationException comes when user presses back button, on cancel button click it remains on same page.